# What files must have references to an image for it to be usable in a MAUI app?

Tags: maui

Beyond the marking of an image as a MauiImage, what files must also have entries regarding the image, e.g., *.vsidx, for it to be usable? I have one new image added to the image resource folder, but not usable like the other 87. I found it missing in a "FileContentIndex" .visdx file but adding it didn't enable it to be usable.

I have searched for other files containing the file names of usable images, and found it listed. Are there any hidden or temp files to be investigated?

Comment: I'm really sorry but I have trouble understanding what you mean here. I don't know what a vsidx file is and I would doubt that this is supported by all platforms to be rendered as an image. If you want to use it as a resource from in your app add it to the Resources/Raw folder and you should be able to read from it if that's what you mean.

Comment: Please provide more details, show some code and explain what exactly is and isn't working. Currently, it's really difficult to understand what's going on. What have you tried that isn't working? How are you referencing the image in question?

Comment: First, even though I have a PNG image in the ..

Comment: First, even though I have a PNG image in the ..\Resources\Images folder and referencing as source for an image in code, it doesn't appear during execution. A vsidx file is a Visual Studio index file created during build in the vs folder. There is also a .csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt file listing images. What other files does the image need to be listed in?

Comment: Try: 1) simplify the filename. Use only lowercase letters and underscore. With `.png` file extension. 2) delete solution's hidden `.vs` folder, and all .bin and .obj folders. 3) Check your `.csproj` file. Does it mention the filename, but with an action of `Remove`? (Or something like that.)

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image#load-a-local-image) :

> Images can be added to your app project by dragging them to the Resources\Images folder of your project, where its build action will automatically be set to MauiImage.

There is nothing more you should do to use the image (everything should be handled by visual studio, the file you mention should be generated). The name of the file is important tho :

> To comply with Android resource naming rules, all local image filenames must be lowercase, start and end with a letter character, and contain only alphanumeric characters or underscores.

So you should check that, there is also that :

> .NET MAUI converts SVG files to PNG files. Therefore, when adding an SVG file to your .NET MAUI app project, it should be referenced from XAML or C# with a .png extension.

Lastly I would try to clean the ./obj and ./bin folders and rebuild the solution. Also if you are testing on a Android / iPhone try uninstalling the debug app to make sure the next install will be clean.

Comment: I have done all those things many times. However, no documentation for the public that speak about the build files that VS uses like those I mentioned. When you have missing entries in them, that's a problem in building a complete application. As I stated in the first sentence, the image is already marked as a MauiImage. Something else is missing.

Comment: @MarcGeorge Evertything else is handled by visual studio so if it's missing that's not like you can change it yourself (anyway VS will most likely rewrite these files). Did you try renaming one of your existing image with the name of the image you are trying to add ? Did you tried to make a clean MAUI project and replace the "dotnet_bot.png" by yours ? Did you try to select the option "Always copy" (just beside "MauiImage") ? Did you try adding this in the csproj `<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\**" />` (Include every folder and files) ?

Comment: As before, VS finally embedded the image after numerous builds with deletions of .vs , ..\appdata\roaming\temp and other folders. I didn't modify the project its. Issue exists but case closed.

Answer (score 0):

Having re-encounter this issue after upgrading to .NET 8 and subsequently resuming research for a solution, I came across this [MAUI Troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/troubleshooting?view=net-maui-8.0). Read the section at the bottom and perform the actions. They resolved the issue.